# MFC: new object - error message?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a class (Event.h):

```
class CEvent 
{
   public:
   CEvent();
   ~CEvent();
   int nVal;
};
```

defined in Event.cpp

```
 #include "event.h"
 CEvent::CEvent() {}
 CEvent::~CEvent() {}
```

In a different class I have included "event.h" and am trying the following:

```
 CEvent* pEvent = new CEvent();
```

But Im getting a compiler error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'CEvent' to 'CEvent *'
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

What am I doing wrong? This is something truly trivial and Im too close to see it.

Using VC 2008.. fwiw..

Comment: I suspect the fault is in some code you're not showing us.

Comment: I can't think of what else is 'interesting'. Its a dialog based app in MFC. I must have some compiler setting that is causing this. I tried to create other standard objects and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

was included in a different class. This was impacting 'new' everywhere! Commenting this out clears the error.

Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

CEvent is also the name of a class in MFC.
I would rename the class to prevent confusion.

Comment: Truthfully - its CMTEvent in the code - I simplified for the question.

Comment: No.. I mean its all "CMTEvent" in my code. When I typed it into StackOverflow I just used "CEvent" instead. I can edit the question if that will simplify this.